# CSS: как сделать плавную смену фона слева направо с помощью animation?

Tags: html, css, анимация

Делаю заливку блока по наведению другим фоном слева направо. Использую для этого "костыль" в виде второго слоя, который просто перемещается туда-сюда.

Но проблема в том, что если в блоке будет текст, то второй слой (равно как и псевдоэлемент) будет его перекрывать. Можно ли реализовать такое с помощью css-анимации? Чтобы просто менялся фон у одного и того же блока слева направо?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner {
  width: 220px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -230px;
  transition: .7s;
}

#wrapper:hover #inner {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вариант с псевдоэлементом - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qsbv7xwy/

Comment: @soledar10, проблема в том, что если в блоке будет текст, то (как и в моём примере), плевдоэлемент будет текст закрывать. Мне нужно, чтобы так менялся именно фон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;  
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,128,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,128,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  transition: left .7s;
}
.wrapper:hover:before{
  left: 0;
}
.block{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну, как вариант, да. Спасибо! Если никто не предложит лучше (с одним блоком), приму Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без анимации

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner {
  width: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: width .7s;
}
#text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:2;
  color:white;
}
#wrapper:hover #inner {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner"></div>\
    <div id="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы невнимательны - мне надо СЛЕВА НАПРАВО

Comment: и чем это отличается от моего варианта? :))

Comment: на вид ни чем, а чем бы ты хотел, чтобы он отличался?)))

Comment: проблема в том, что если в блоке текст, то при таком варианте он закрывается. мне нужно, чтобы менялся именно фон и именно слева направо

Comment: Этот же пример можно реализовать и с помощью псевдо-элементов `::after  и ::before`